# Chef use "cookbook_file" as source for "windows_zipfile" resource

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to use windows_zipfile resource from the "windows" cookbook, but the file i need to unzip is located at files/default in the cookbook I'm running.

Normally I would access this file using the "cookbook_file" resource, how can I get to it with windows_zipfile resource?

I've tried:

```
windows_zipfile 'c:\test_app' do
    source 'files/default/test_app.zip'
    action :unzip
end
```

and got "File files\default\test_zpp.zip not found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the file locally, then run your windows_zipfile resource.  You're trying to unzip a file inside your repo, not on your node.  The `source` here is the file on the local filesystem.

```
cookbook_file 'c:/testapp.zip' do
  source 'files/default/test_app.zip'
end

windows_zipfile 'c:/test_app' do
  source 'c:/testapp.zip'
  action :unzip
  not_if {::File.exists?('c:/test_app')}
end
```

^Also, make sure you include a `not_if` guard to protect idempotence (so that each Chef run won't try to unzip).

This is mentioned in the windows cookbook.

Comment: that gave me: NoMethodError undefined method 'source' for Chef::Resource::File

Comment: apologies, this needs to be `cookbook_file` not `file` as it's source is in the cookbook.

Comment: is there any way we can append username and password for windows_zipfile resource to fetch the source files @Cony?